# Angular JS Do Not Pass If Ng-disabled is TRUE

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have something like

```
<input type='text' ng-model='SampleDTO'>

<input type='text' ng-model='SampleDTO2' ng-disabled='SampleDTO == null'>
```

What happens is I place a value for the first input the place another for the second, then I remove the value of the first input so the second input is disabled. When I pass the values to the controller the disabled field is also included. How can I prevent disabled fields from being passed to the controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way:

```
<input type='text' ng-model='SampleDTO2' ng-if='SampleDTO != null'>
```

In this case this field will disappear (depending on condition) and model will not be bound to it

Comment: wow thats neat! I needed that ahahaha, but to the current problem, its in the requirement that the fields should be visible. (And in some requirement the text should be invisible depending on condition Thanks!!)

Answer (score 0):

If you  want to show the disabled text field. Try this way

```
<input type='text' ng-model='SampleDTO'>

<input type='text'  ng-disabled='SampleDTO == null' ng-if='SampleDTO == null'>

<input type='text' ng-model='SampleDTO2' ng-if='SampleDTO != null'>
```

By doing this way UI will a disabled text box with no scope attached to it.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks! This is great but I'll have to consult the designers if theyll allow me to do this. Anyways, this can be a backup plan for me. Thanks man!

Answer (score 0):

You can just add a ng-hide for the same purpose as follows:

```
<input type='text'  ng-disabled='SampleDTO == null' ng-model='SampleDTO2' ng-hide='SampleDTO == null' >
```